# moving an uploaded file is not working

Tags: php, upload

I've looked around similar questions to this one here, but none seems to work for me, my code does not upload file to new directory. It only returns the set error "file could not be uploaded"
Please help

```
if ($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
{
if ($_FILES["imgfile"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["imgfile"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgfile"]["tmp_name"],
"upload/" . $_FILES["imgfile"]["name"]);
echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["imgfile"]["name"];
echo "<br> File uploaded successfully.";
}
}
else
{
echo "File could not be uploaded.";
}
```

Comment: no warning from "move_uploaded_file" ? you have error check and display yon

Comment: It means that your first condition is failing `$_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"`.

Comment: check in your php.ini:  file_uploads = On

Comment: Use `var_dump($_FILES);` at the top. Check the `type` - it may not be what you're looking for. You may want to prepend the file name with something unique, like `substr(md5(microtime()), 0, 5)` . Otherwise, see Nabil's comment about the enctype.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set the enctype attribute to multipart/form-data in the form

Comment: yes the enctype on the form tag is set to multipart/form-data

Comment: check the permissions of files and folders

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have set the enctype attribute to multipart/form-data,
then try this,

```
$name=$_FILES['imgfile']['name'];
$path="upload/".$name;
$type=$_FILES['imgfile']['type'];
$pos=strpos($type,'image');
if($pos===false)
{
    //error
}
else
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgfile']['tmp_name'],$path);
}
```

Comment: im sorry but, i copied and pasted your code, and I made sure the enctype is set to multipart/form-data, also checked the spelling... The file is still not moving